# Display First Name instead of UserName in welcome greeting of VB Web Form App

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

The stock visual basic web forms app template in Visual Studio 2017 displays a welcome message with the UserName field displayed (i.e. "Hello, abc@123.com"). I need to display it with the FirstName field displayed instead (i.e. "Hello, John).

There are numerous other posts about this but none of them have solved my problem.  I have added the FirstName property to the identitymodels.vb file as follows:

```
Private FName As String
    Public Property FirstName() As String
        Get
            Return FName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            FName = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

However, the FirstName property does not seem to be exposed in the sitemaster.aspx file.  I have also tried FName with the same results.

Currently in the sitemaster.aspx file the UserName is displayed by:

```
<li>
<a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %>!</a>
</li>
```

I need something like,

```
<li>
<a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetFirstName()  %>!</a>
</li>
```

but the "GetFirstName part does not work.  I assume that GetUserName is a predefined method and I need to be able to predefine a new method that returns the FirstName field instead of the the UserName field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user logs in you can display the profile information by doing the following:

1. Add a function in the code behind of `Site.Master` to get the User object:

```vb
Protected Function Get_Current_User() As ApplicationUser
    Dim manager = New UserManager(Of ApplicationUser)(New UserStore(Of ApplicationUser)(New ApplicationDbContext()))
    Dim currentUser = manager.FindById(Context.User.Identity.GetUserId())
    Return currentUser
End Function
```

2. Invoke it in your markup:

```html
<li>
    <a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">
        Hello, <%: Get_Current_User().FirstName  %>!
    </a>
</li>
```

You need the following imports for the above code to work:

```vb
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
```

As a reference, here's an article that describes it nicely (in C#):

[Customizing profile information in ASP.NET Identity in VS templates](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates/)

Comment: Well I tried this and read the article.  However, I get the following error: "Type 'UserStore' is not defined.  I have the following imports at the top of the site.master.vb file:  '''Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb'''  Shouldn't 'UserStore' be included with Owin?

Comment: @jamie-dixson You need these two imports: `Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` and
`Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework`. I've updated my answer, too.